# Using WGET to simulate web activity

Tags: bash, shell, wget

I'm currently writing a Bash script to simulate web activity. The idea is the script runs for approximately three hours, then terminates.

I've no problem with wget, the oneliner works perfectly at the cmd line
Code is here:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=$(date +%s)
echo current time is $a
b=$(($a + 10800))   # finish time is start time plus 10800 number of seco\
                # nds in three hours
echo finish time is $b
for line in "url_list.txt"; do
     echo current url is $line
     date=$(date +%s)
     echo current time is $c
     wget -e \
       -r -p -l 1 -T 60 \
       --random-wait --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092416 Firefox/3.0.3" \
       --convert-links\
     echo "downloading..." 
     echo "Calculating if three hours has passed..."
     if (("$date" > "$b"))
     then
         echo "3 hours has passed£
         break
     else
         echo sleep for 5 seconds
         sleep 5;
     done;
```

I'm getting the error:

```
url_request.sh: line 26: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
url_request.sh: line 26: `      done'
```

What's going on, that I cannot see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final Script for future Googlers... I canned the for loop as I'm going to use a Cron job instead

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IN="http://download.thinkbroadband.com/50MB.zip;http://www.bbc.co.uk;http://www.few.vu.nl/~kgr700/cloud%20computing%20and%20emerging%20it%20platforms.pdf;http://www.theregister.co.uk;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cloud_computing"

arr=$(echo $IN | tr ";" "\n")

while true; do
    for x in $arr
    do
    echo downloading $x
    wget -r -p -l 2 -T 60 $x --random-wait --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092416 Firefox/3.0.3" --convert-links -a logfile.txt
    done
done
```

Comment: You can define IN with spaces instead and then use directly `for x in $IN; do` like in [my version](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/6f3abb42685237dfca16) and "few.vu.nl/~kgr700/.." is empty

Answer (score 4):

in bash you end an `if` construct with `fi`, not `done`